# MSAccess - CSV TransferText Import Spec, non-ascii delimiter?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I receive a CSV file from a 3rd party I need to IMPORT into Access.  They claim they are unable to add any sort of Text Qualifier; all my common delimiter options (comma, tabs, pipe, $, ~, ^, etc.) all seem to appear in the data, so not reliable to use in an Import Spec.  I cannot edit the data, but we can adjust the delimiter.  Record counts are in 500K range x 50 columns (250MB).

I tried a non-ascii char as a delimiter (i.e., ÿ), I can add to an Import Spec, the sample data appears to delimit OK, but get a error (Subscript out of Range) when attempting the actual Import.  Also tried a multi-character delimiter, but no-go.

Any suggestions to permit me to receive these csv tables?  Daily task, many low-skilled users, remote locations, import function behind a button.

Sample Raw Data, truncated for width (June7, not sure if this helps the discussion)

```
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219417ÿ9033504ÿ9033504ÿPUNCH BIOPSY 4MM UNI-PUNCH SS SEAMLS RAZOR SHARP BLADE...
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219418ÿ1673BXÿ1673BXÿCLEANER INST 1GL KLENZYME LATEXÿSTERIS PLCÿ1673BXÿ1673BX...
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219419ÿA4823PRÿA4823PRÿBAG BIOHAZ THK1.3 MIL 24X23IN RED LDPE PRINT INF WASTE...
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219420ÿCUR9225ÿCUR9225ÿGLOVE EXAM CURAD MEDIUM LATEX FREEÿMEDLINE INDUSTRIES,...
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219421ÿCUR9226ÿCUR9226ÿGLOVE EXAM CURAD LARGE LATEX FREEÿMEDLINE INDUSTRIES, ...
9798ÿ9798ÿ451219422ÿ90176101ÿ90176101ÿDRAPE CONSUMABLE PK EQUIP OEC UROVIEW 2800 STERILE L...
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data - as text not image. If they don't include delimiter character in file, exactly how are you using the special character as delimiter?

Comment: June7 - inserted sample data - you can see the last delimiter attempt: ÿ  Actual data is VERY WIDE.

Comment: Following up:  3rd party can adjust the delimiter to whatever I request, but they cannot adjust the actual data values...which can contain some the more common delimiter values.

Comment: I tested import with wizard and get 'Type Conversion Failure' import error on every row for Field1. Turns out the wizard ignores that character and simply imports each row as a single long string into Field1. Although it does create 6 fields in table. Weird. I've never had to use Import Specs so no idea how it handles this character. Alternatives are to read the text file with VBA one line at a time or import the long string and use VBA to parse the table field.

Comment: June7, I think we are seeing the same issue, just from two different angles.  That ÿ character is unacceptable to the import process.

I just manually confirmed, every single character on my ascii keyboard appears in an actual extract w/440K rows x 50 columns.  The data is coming from a SQL table export, which I do not control.

Comment: Do they have the capacity to switch to fixed-width exports, or wrap each data element of the csv in quotes?

Comment: Fixed width might be possible; I'll inquire.  They claim quoted text is not available.

Comment: I got rid of the ÿ delimiter using Excel (Office 365). Might help you to come up with a structural solution. I saved your sample data as a csv file. Next I imported the csv data file in Excel (get data from txt/csv). Selecting the file triggers an import wizard. As for file origin, I did NOT select any encoding. As for Delimiter I chose Custom and entered the ÿ character as delimiter. I did not opt for Data Type Detection.No errors, all data was neatly split in 6 columns, ÿ character no longer shows.

Comment: General CSV specifications exist but aren't widely accepted and CSV is a weak format because it requires a lot of metadata not present in the file. However, I've never seen a CSV specification that didn't accommodate the field separator character appearing in the data (e.g., Text Qualifier).  It seems incumbent upon the sender to choose and communicate a format that is sufficient for the desired data transfer and parsing. Or, just use a better open-standards defined format, like .xlsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another extended-ASCII character (128 - 254).  The chosen delimiter ÿ (255) apparently doesn't work, but it's already a suspicious character since it has all bits set and sometimes has special meaning for that reason.

It's also good to consider the code page.  If you're in the US using standard English version of Windows, its likely that Access is using the default "Western European (Windows)" (Windows-1252) code page.  But if you're outside the US or have other languages installed, it could be that the particular default code page will treat certain characters differently.  For reference, I'm using Access 2013 on Windows 10.  In the Access text import wizard, clicking on the [Advanced...] button shows more options, including the selection of the import code page.  Since you're having problems with the import, it is worth inspecting that settings.

For the record, I had similar results as you and others using the sample data and delimiter ÿ (255).

Next I tried **À (192)** which is a standard letter character in various code pages, so it should likely work even if the default were not Windows-1252.  Indeed, **it worked** on my system and resulted in no errors.

To get the import working without errors at first, I would choose all *Short Text* and *Long Text* fields before specifying integer, date or other non-text types.  If all text columns work, then try specific fields types.  In this way, you can at least differentiate between delimiter errors and other data errors.

---

This isn't to discourage other options like fixed-width text, especially since in that case you won't have to worry about the delimiter at all.

Comment: You could even test this without having the 3rd party reproduce the export.  Just open the data file in a text editor and replace the delimiters.

Comment: Replacing delimiter with (À) does import without error, but now, with a typical/full dataset, I am seeing carriage returns in the data, which totally mucks up the import.  2200 rows in this 220K recordset.   This would break the fixed-width approach too.

They really need to figure out a way to quote those text values.

This import routine would be performed many times per day by many users in US and India, most of which are non-technical.  This needs to be automated.  

Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Maybe via some replace function (in the txt file before import) I can replace À with a quoted pipe ('|'), and then insert a leading and trailing (') to each row string.  This is getting messy.

Comment: I decided to answer your immediate problem surrounding the Access import feature, but there are other solutions to your overall problem.  You already stated that the import process is "behind a button", so don't be afraid to add necessary processing to the text file.  I suggest looking into regular expression tools (e.g. from the Unix heritage like `grep` and `awk`), or directly within Access VBA using the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression" library (by adding a VBA reference) which has basic-but-useful functionality.